# Contact form does not work

Tags: forms, emails

I configured the contact form module core for drupal 7, But the messages are not sent, whitout any error message. I work just in local.

Comment: Your explanation is too short to understand. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Can your Drupal send any mails at all?

Comment: did you install the SMTP module?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your localhost is capable of sending e-mails? (probably not, mine for example can't send an email)